# Having number above 60 in "ss" format

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
Global time As Date

Sub countdown()
time = Now()
time = DateAdd("s", 120, time)

Do Until time < Now()
DoEvents
oSh.TextFrame.TextRange = Format((time - Now()), "ss")
Loop
End Sub
```

The timer starts from `60` and ends at `00`. Then the same repeats. Is it possible to start the timer from 120 directly? How can we go about it?

Comment: Try `(Minute(Time - Now) * 60) + Second(Time - Now)`. Note: `Time` is a [VBA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/time-function) so you should avoid naming your variable as simply `time`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *DateDiff*:

```vb
Global StopTime As Date

Sub countdown()

    StopTime = DateAdd("s", 120, Now)

    Do Until StopTime < Now
        DoEvents
        oSh.TextFrame.TextRange = DateDiff("s", Now, StopTime)
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Format will simply read the seconds from a date value, there is no way to "force" it to calculate the total seconds. However, it is rather easy to calculate it manually:

```
Dim delta as Date
delta = t - now
oSh.TextFrame.TextRange = Minute(d) * 60 + Second(d)
' or, if you want to have always 3 digits, eg 030
oSh.TextFrame.TextRange = Format(Minute(d) * 60 + Second(d), "000")
```